# Issue with onRequestPermissionsResult()

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I'm able to grant or deny permissions in my fragment but I'm trying to call a method when permission has been granted but it doesn't seem to get called.

```
public final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
```

I**n onCreateView(): (This works)**

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            retrieveGyms();
        } else {
            this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
        }
```

**retrieveGyms() is not called when permission is granted from dialog, but permission does get granted.**

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
                if (permissions.length == 1 && permissions[0] == Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    retrieveGyms();
                } else {
                    // Location permission denied.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Showing retrieveGyms() just to show what it does and what I'm expecting**

```
public void retrieveGyms() {
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get("https://gyminyapp.azurewebsites.net/api/Gym", null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
                gymsArray = response;

                // HashMap<String, Object> returnedGyms = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                for (int i = 0; i < gymsArray.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        // TODO: check distance from current user location and remove if not within search radius

                        String latitude = gymsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("latitude");
                        String longitude = gymsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("longitude");
                        Double doubleLat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
                        Double doubleLong = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
                        LatLng gymCoord = new LatLng(doubleLat, doubleLong);

                        String name = gymsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");

                        Object gymAddress = gymsArray.getJSONObject(i).get("address");
                        JSONObject gymAddressJSONObj = (JSONObject)gymAddress;
                        String streetAddress = gymAddressJSONObj.getString("streetAddress");
                        String city = gymAddressJSONObj.getString("city");
                        String state = gymAddressJSONObj.getString("state");
                        int zipCode = gymAddressJSONObj.getInt("zipCode");
                        String zipCodeString = Integer.toString(zipCode);

                        String addressString = streetAddress + " " + city + ", " + state + " " + zipCodeString;

                        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_marker))
                                .flat(false)
                                .title(name)
                                .snippet(addressString)
                                .position(gymCoord));

                        // Add marker to markers array
                        markers.add(marker);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Zoom map to fit all markers
                    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                    for (Marker marker : markers) {
                        builder.include(marker.getPosition());
                    }
                    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

                    int padding = 75;
                    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
                    mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable e) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Does activity have **android:excludeFromRecents="true"**?

Comment: Is onRequestPermissionResult() in your activity?

Comment: No to both of those questions.